# MOSFET N-Channel voltage follower near gate threshold

Tags: mosfet

I'm analyzing a MOSFET circuit that was designed to be a voltage follower:

[image]

I'm doubting if this circuit will work as intended. I analyzed this using the load-line method:

[image]

So my argument is, based on my Q-point analysis, that this circuit is very close to the edge of not exceeding the gate threshold voltage, which varies with temperature as well. So if it can't conduct, it can't perform the intended operation.

Does that sound correct, or am I misinterpreting something?

Active high enable is driving the "EN" pin of a LMR14050 switching regulator. The spec sheet for this part claims the current draw of about 5 microamps for that pin. The intention of this circuit is for a 0V on the "Active-Low Reset" to disable the LMR14050 switching regulator, and a 12V on the "Active-Low Reset" to enable the LMR14050 switching regulator.

Datasheet for [LMR14050](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr14050.pdf?ts=1628779917146&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

Datasheet for [BSS138](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/bss138lt1-d.pdf)

Comment: Why don't you tell us what "as intended" means? What **exactly** are you connecting to the output? How much current will it draw? What output voltages do you expect/require?

Comment: yeah, that would be better as a PFET.

Comment: You would need to know what the load of "active high" to really answer this question, use a pmos for high side switching.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson  I've added additional information to address your comments.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I've added additional information to address your comments.

Comment: LMR14050 has internal pull-up on EN pin. What is your VIN on LMR14050? If it's the same +12V, you don't need MOSFET at all and can connect your "Active-low Reset directly" as you don't need inverted logic based on your description.

Comment: VIN is 12V. As a general comment: I am not designing a circuit. This is the circuit that has already been designed (by someone else), and I am only trying to determine if it will work or not. So making suggestions about changing the circuit to make it better is not going to be applicable.

Comment: Please provide a link to the datasheet for the LM$14050. I don't believe that it needs 12 V on the enable if its supply voltage is also 12V.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Added datasheet. Again, I'm not looking for suggestions on how to modify the circuit, just whether or not the provided circuit will work as shown.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson it doesn't needs +12V (but max is at 40V, while threshold is 1.38V max), but it has internal pull-up to it's VIN so it will source some current.

Comment: It only needs about 1.5 V on the enable. So, what is the leakage current of the MOSFET when Vgs = 0? Does that current plus the input current of the regulator keep the voltage on EN low enough when it flows through 10k?